# Silverlight Open Child Window counter

Tags: silverlight, counter, childwindow

I have a silverlight application which uses a child window as a processing dialog. The child window open can be called from more that one event.

What I would like to do is to add a counter to the Child Window Show() that increments by one on each call. That way, I should then be able to only call the Close() if the counter is at zero. This would allow for all the completed events to run and call a Close() and decrement the value by one with each call.

To be honest I'm not sure where to start with this one but any help or guidance would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not 100% clear what you are trying to accomplish, but a good way to retrieve all your opened childwindow objects is the following method :

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups()
```

Note that this is available since Silverlight version 4.0 only

Good luck.

Comment: Meant to type more. What I have are 2 user controls on the same page which load data. As the calls can take a few seconds, I added a childwindow which has a "processor" spinner to advise the user of loading. Each of the user controls have thier own completed events and also both call the Childwindow.show(). As the controls can take different amounts of time depending on data, and because I only want the child window to close when both events are completed, I wanted to count the number of Show() that are called and in completed events, decrese the value until in reaches 0 and only then, close.